# Node.js http request memory and cpu hog

Tags: node.js

I have a node.js script that continuously requests a page, sort of like a cron job.

However, after a few minutes Node starts to use a lot of CPU (up to 70%) and memory (up to 200mb).

**What is wrong with my script?**

```
function cron(path)
{
    var http = require('http');
    var site = http.createClient(443, 'www.website.com', true);
    var request = site.request('GET', path, {'host': 'www.website.com'});
    request.end();

    request.on('response', function (response) {

        setTimeout(function(){cron(path)},15000);
    });


}

cron('/path/to/page');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
request.on('response', function (response) {
    setTimeout(function(){cron(path)},15000);
});
```

For every response you create a new `cron` job. Log your responses. If your getting more then 1 from your request then your exponantially creating more cron jobs.

Your creating a `function() {}` with a reference to `path`. So the entire scope state is kept. you want to free memory by adding this:

```
var site = null;
var request = null;
```

Your calling `require("http")` inside a function rather then outside in module scope. You only need to get `http` once so place at the top of your file in module scope.

```
var http = require('http');
var site = http.createClient(443, 'www.website.com', true);
function cron(path)
{

    var request = site.request('GET', path, {'host': 'www.website.com'});
    request.end();

    var once = true;
    request.on('response', doIt);

    function doIt(response) {
        if (!once) {
            once = null;
            doIt = function() {};
            setTimeout(function(){cron(path)},15000);
        }
    });

    site = null;
    request = null;
}

cron('/path/to/page');
```

Comment: Great, I am testing the new script now. I don't see why you use the "once" variable inside the request.on() callback, every request can have only one response right?

Comment: @koen to make sure it only gets called once. Did you want to create a new `cron` job when you get _a_ response or did you want to create a new `cron` job for _every_ response you get from a request. Note that some of my "optimizations" may be done by the V8 interpreter for you. I don't know enough about V8 to see know when they release their memory, setting variables to `null` when there not needed is basically flagging that memory for cleaning by the GC.

Comment: I want to create a new response when the old request is finished. Sometimes the page takes longer to load and I only want one cron at the same time, that's why I use the request.on() callback. I just checked and the page returns only one response.

Comment: @koen then I have difficulty explaining the CPU usage. Place some console.log's in various places including timestamps (`Date.now();`) to see whether cron get's called more then once per 15 seconds.

Comment: @Koen the client is probably not getting cleaned up internally. You dont need a new one per `cron` job. Create a single one. See editted answer.

Comment: Moving the http client outside of cron() seemed to have fixed the leak! I am currently watching the memory usage.

Comment: @koen there may be some method on the client like `close`. I could not find anything in the API. Feel free to `console.dir(client)` and see if you can find a method that cleans the client up.

Comment: @Raynos, thanks for your help, issue is fixed :) CPU seems to be slightly high, but not troublesome.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the tips from @Raynos, here's another. I find that recursive calls like this in long running processes make me a bit nervous so I'd err on the side of using [setInterval](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.7/api/globals.html#setInterval) instead. I'd maybe split the cron and the http behaviour apart in case you want to try and re-use that logic, although that'll depend on your context:

e.g. in node 0.4.7:

```
var https = require('https');

function poll(path)
{
    https.get({
        host: 'www.website.com',
        port: 443,
        path: path
    }, function(res) {
        console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
    }).on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
    });

}

function cron(path)
{
    return setInterval(function(){
        poll(path);
    },15000);
}

var intervalId = cron('/path/to/page'); // keep in case you need to use clearInterval
```